# Typed data to buffer in C

Tags: c

I have a function with this signature :

```
void my_func(uint8_t param1, uint8_t param2, uint8_t* array, uint8_t array_length)
```

Parameters given must be placed in a buffer like this :

```
uint8_t buff = {param1, param2, array[0], ..., array[length - 1], array_length};
```

and given as parameter to a non modifiable function taking a buffer and its length.

```
void consume(uint8_t* buff, uint8_t length)
```

In my_func I can create a buffer of size :

```
sizeof(param1) + sizeof(param2) + array_length
```

but it uses extra memory for an already existing array.

As a non portable solution I would prefer using a packed struct and define my_func like this :

```
typedef struct __attribute__((packed))
{
  uint8_t param1; 
  uint8_t param2;
  uint8_t array[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE];
  uint8_t array_length;
}TsMyStruct;

void my_func(TsMyStruct*);
```

With this solution I can directly cast TsMyStruct* to uint8_t* and give it to consume() function :

```
consume(uint8_t* (mystruct), sizeof(TsMyStruct))
```

A drawback of this solution is that for array of size < MAX_ARRAY_SIZE this solution is not better than first proposition.

Have you some other proposals (not using malloc)?

Comment: That doesn't make sense: If you don't know the length of the variable data in the buffer, you also don't know where to find the by that tells you this length.

Comment: You need to look up malloc().

Comment: Sorry, I've forgot to precise that I need a non malloc based solution (code running on very limited memory hardware with no dynamic allocation)

Answer (score 1):

when you can swap `array` and `array_length` (I do not see, how your order makes sense with a dynamic `array_length`), you can write

```
struct foo {
  uint8_t param1;
  uint8_t param2;
  uint8_t array_length;
  uint8_t array[]
};
```

and allocate + fill it like

```
struct foo *buf = malloc(sizeof *buf + array_length);

buf->param1 = param1;
buf->param2 = param2;
buf->array_length = array_length;
memcpy(buf->array, array, array_length);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create an array of pointers of size 4, where the first element is a pointer to param1, and the second element is a pointer to param2, and the third element is a pointer to your array, and the fourth element is a pointer to the size of your array.

```
uint8_t* arrayOfPointers[4]={&param1,&param2,&array,&array_length};
uint8_t* buff = arrayOfPointers;
```